# ¿como localizar un dato, otorgando 2 parametros en un SpreadSheet con Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando obtener un dato, recuperando 2 parámetros (**código y fecha**) capturados en un `formulario HTML` de `Google Apps Script`, sin embargo, hasta el momento solo he logrado con el **código**, obtener el dato de la segunda columna, y me lo muestra correctamente:

Esta es mi tabla de la hoja de calculo:

[image: Tabla en la hoja de calculo]

Este es mi formulario mostrando el dato:

[image: Formulario HTML]

Este es mi formulario:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="codigo" class="autocomplete">
<label for="codigo">Introduce el nombre del producto</label>
<input id="fecha" type="text" class="datepicker">
<label for="fecha">Selecciona la fecha</label>
<input disabled value="" id="ventas" type="text" class="validate">
<label for="ventas">Cantidad vendida</label>
<button id="btnCon">Consultar ventas</button>
</form>
```

Este es el código de mi script:

```js
<script>         
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

document.getElementById("btnCon").addEventListener("click",conVentas);

     });   

 var codigoBox = document.getElementById("codigo");
 var fechaBox = document.getElementById("fecha"); 

function conVentas(){
   var codigo = codigoBox.value;
   var fecha = fechaBox.value;

   if (codigo.trim().length == 0 || fecha.trim().length == 0){
      M.toast({html: 'Por favor introduce todos los datos'});
   }else{       
             google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateStock).getDetalleVentas(codigo);

    M.toast({html: 'Consulta realizada con exito!'});
        }//else
 }//conVentas

function updateStock(cost){
   document.getElementById("ventas").value = cost;
   M.updateTextFields();

 }
</script>
```

Y este es el código de secuencia de comandos (gs) de `Google Apps Script`:

```js
function getDetalleVentas(codigo){

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("VENTAS");

   var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();

   var firstCol = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
   var secondCol = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });

   var position = firstCol.indexOf(codigo);
   if(position > -1){
     return secondCol[position];
   }else{
     return 'fecha no existente';
   }

}
```

Tal como lo tengo ahora no es lo que estoy buscando, ya que aún no he podido tomar el segundo parámetro, la **fecha**, y obtener el dato que esta en la intersección, tal como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber que puedo modificar en mi código de secuencia de comandos y/o mi script para tomar los 2 parámetros y obtener el dato que requiero.

Comment: Stack Snippet usualmente no debe usarse con Google Apps Script porque Stack Snippet es sólo para código HTML/CSS/JavaScript ejecutable (al hacer clic en Ejecutar muestra un resultado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo se trata de encontrar una celda en una tabla de doble entrada: se debe buscar las coincidencias en los encabezados de fila y los encabezados de columna.

Para simplificar las cosas puedes reemplazar

```
var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

por

```
var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
```

En tu código ya obtienes el indice de fila. Para obtener el índice de columna puedes usar algo como esto

```
var colIdx = data[0].indexOf(valor_a_buscar)
```

Luego para obtener el dato

```
var dato = data[filaIdx][colIdx]
```

donde `filaIdx` es el índice de fila, en tu código usas la variable `position`

---

IMPORTANTE

No está claro si los encabezados de columna son valores de tipo fecha o de tipo texto. Si fueran tipo fecha es importante tener presente que Google Apps Script y las hojas de cálculo de Google manejan las fechas de forma diferente y aunque al leer / escribir este tipo de valores Google Apps Script se hace cargo de la conversión hay que tener presente cómo funciona, mientras que en la hoja de cálculo la unidad de los números seriales que representan fechas es un día, en Google Apps Script/JavaScript es un milisegundo.

Quizás lo más sencillo sería en lugar de usar `getValues()` usar `getDisplayValues()` y usar como argumento de `indexOf` una cadena de texto en lugar de un objeto de tipo fecha.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡funciono perfecto!

Comment: @skygazermuerto Si te ha funcionado acepta la respuesta. ref. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
 function getDetalleVentas(codcol, codfil ) {

  //var codcol =  new Date('2019-07-02T00:00:00');
  //var codfil = "SQ2";

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ws = ss.getSheetByName("VENTAS");

 var vfil_ini = 1, vcol_ini = 1;

 var data = ws.getRange(vfil_ini, vcol_ini, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn())
              .getValues();



 // Recupera el Titulo Horizontal del rango
 var ArrayTitulo_Horizontal = [];
 var Arrayaux = data[0];
 for ( d in Arrayaux ){
    ArrayTitulo_Horizontal.push( Arrayaux[d].toString() );
 };
 var poscol = ArrayTitulo_Horizontal.indexOf( codcol.toString() );

  // recupera Titulo Vertical             
 var ArrayTitulo_Vertical = data.map(function(val){ 
          return val[0]; 
      });
 var posfil = ArrayTitulo_Vertical.indexOf(codfil);

 //Logger.log( ArrayTitulo_Horizontal );
 //Logger.log( ArrayTitulo_Vertical );
 //Logger.log( poscol + ", "+posfil )
 Logger.log( "valor = " +data[posfil][poscol] ) ;


    }
```